# WordPress FTP settings for AWS EC2

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ftp, sftp

I have WordPress installed on AWS with EC2. I can connect via SFTP using FileZilla but if I try to update a plugin from within WordPress it asks me for the FTP details and I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: There was an error connecting to the server, Please verify the settings are correct.
```

I've read a lot of threads on here and followed a lot of steps to try to rectify, including:

- added 2 new inbound Custom TCP rules to the EC2 Security Group; one for port 21 and one for ports 0-65000
- added the following to my wp-config.ini:

  ```
  define('FS_METHOD', 'ftpext');
  define('FTP_BASE', '/var/www/');
  define('FTP_CONTENT_DIR', '/var/www/wp-content/');
  define('FTP_PLUGIN_DIR ', '/var/www/wp-content/plugins/');
  define('FTP_USER', 'ubuntu');
  define('FTP_PASS', 'my_password_obviously');
  define('FTP_HOST', 'my.ip.obviously');
  define('FTP_SSL', false);
  ```

still no luck. can anyone help?

Thanks
Sean

Comment: FTP is very insecure. I am assuming you have put a lot of thought into it but just thought I'd point out... If you can stick with SFTP using a security key it is a far better solution and more secure.

Comment: I haven't put that much thought into it. could you please elaborate? until now I've been using Filezilla (SFTP) for plugin updates but now I need to update my WordPress core and that's a bit trickier using Filezilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are on ec2, you have full control of your instance. You can use `direct` setting for FS_METHOD as a means of updating the core and any plugins.

Although keep in mind that this can be somewhat insecure if you do not properly configure your instance (The webserver user should be isolated). You would also want to be sure that you can trust the plugins your are installing.

Comment: Thanks datasage. I got a new error message "could not copy files". so I tried updating a plugin instead and got the error message "could not remove the old plugin". so I changed the plugins folder permissions from 755 to 777. is that bad? and should I do that for the core files to update the core?

Comment: I wouldn't set it to 777, instead set the files to be owned by the web server user (usually `apache` or `httpd`)

Comment: Great, I ended up doing that in the end using the following command: `sudo chown -R www-data rusama.net/`. I will change the permissions back to 755 now. Do I still need those TCP rules I cerated in AWS?

Comment: Not for using the direct option. It will download and install files directly on your instance. Wordpress will apply some security updates automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon EC2 has some issues with FTP. See [here](http://linuxadminzone.com/install-and-configure-ftp-server-in-amazon-ec2-instance/) for a solution to this common issue. However, this may not be your **best** solution. I go by the philosophy that the fewer ports I can open, the safer I am. Even if you are keeping it open only to your local IP, you are not completely safe from a DoS or some other malicious attack. Multiple checks are better than one, and fewer ports are better than more.

The issue is that FTP is that it was designed and implemented prior to any of today's security concerns. While you can make FTP more secure, and there are solutions on the web for this (like the one above), a better - and possibly MUCH easier - solution could be found in allowing FTPS over Port 22. Evidently, by installing and activating some packages you may be able to open Wordpress updates to a new option.

See [here](http://snowulf.com/2010/06/29/wordpress-enabling-sshsftp-updates/) (not tested by me) for the FTPS solution which runs through Port 22 by binding to PHP through `libssh2-php` on Debian (or [these steps](http://blog.dynamichosting.biz/2011/01/10/installing-ssh2-extension-for-php-on-centos-5/) on CentOS).

Comment: Thanks but I already have SSH/SFTP working through Filezilla so I'm not sure that's going to help.

Comment: You can use FTPS without having the bindings for PHP. WordPress can't use it without the PHP bindings.